# Installing Ubuntu on Nexus 7

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 as mentioned in the [official wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) . However, when I run the Ubuntu Nexus7 installer I get an error saying that it cannot download the content (My connection is working correctly).
I tried to do it manually as mentioned the official wiki post as well, they said I should download the image from  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-preinstalled/current/ but it shows the 404 error!
Help me please, I have already unlocked the bootloader and lost all my data.

Comment: Try http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/.

Comment: If the ppa installs, but doesn't seem to work, maybe you should file a bug against ppa:ubuntu-nexus7/ubuntu-nexus7-installer or give more detail on what's failing aside from a url being possibly incorrect on the wiki (which would be files as a bug as well).

Comment: it does not show an error number, it simply says that it cannot download. Regarding the Wiki, if you follow the links you can see that it has changed and it is giving error 404. @hbdgaf

Comment: @Danatela How am I supposed to download that image folder? a file after a file? and when I'm done, how to "gun-zip" the files? I really did not get this step :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation instructions you were using are for **ubuntu-core**, a desktop build for the **Nexus 7**.

This is not currently being maintained (or further developed). The code base will be merged into the current **phablet** codebase, once they move beyond their focus on *phones* and *phone/tablets* .. (to tablets and touch-screen desktops).

---

### How to install Ubuntu-Touch 13.10 (beta)

There are easy to follow instructions at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

The builds can be found at: 
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/

---

However, it is even simpler to use the **phablet-flash** command-line tool.

*You can (optionally) download the files, before you have a device attached.*

### Download files: (full install)

*current ------*  **`phablet-flash -d grouper -b -D`**

*daily build --*  **`phablet-flash -d grouper -b -D --pending`**

### Download files: (updates)

*current ------*  **`phablet-flash -d grouper -D`**

*daily build --*  **`phablet-flash -d grouper -D --pending`**

*There are a number of different ways to install.*

### Install to device (full install):

*current ------*  **`phablet-flash -b`**

*daily build --*  **`phablet-flash -b --pending`**

### Install to device (updates):

*current ------*  **`phablet-flash`**

*daily build --*  **`phablet-flash --pending`**

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any idea on when is the official phone/ tablet Ubuntu is coming?

Comment: This will be 'beta' for 2013-Oct, with final release for 2014-Apr. See: http://www.xda-developers.com/android/canonical-announces-ubuntu-for-phones-coming-soon-to-galaxy-nexus/ 'What Lies Ahead?'

Comment: I tried these but then the terminal tells me that there is not enough arguments...? =

Comment: Yes. The syntax has changed, and needs an extra argument. Change the start of each command from **`phablet-flash `** to **`phablet-flash cdimage-touch `**. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/336635/ubuntu-touch-install-syntax-error OR http://askubuntu.com/questions/342412/phablet-flash-error-too-few-arguments

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guide for the Nexus 7. [Instructions for flashing a phone or tablet device with Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)

Comment: The command "phablet-flash -b" is supposed to download some files, but it did not. I checked the download folder in my Nexus 7 and on my PC, I couldn't find anything.
I have a slow connection (University campus connection), Could that be the reason?

Comment: What are the errors? phablet-flash -d grouper -b

Comment: It does not give a number, it just says error :-/