# Install Ubuntu 13.10 daily builds on Nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, 13.10

I could be getting a Nexus 7 soon (yay). And Tempted to take Ubuntu Unity (not touch, well later), for a spin on it.
On the Ubuntu wikipage you can install 13.04 on it, which is great, but I am wondering how I could get 13.10 daily builds on the Nexus 7. If it is possible.

Thank you for your time and answes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to install Ubuntu-Touch 13.10 (beta)

There are easy to follow instructions at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

The builds can be found at: 
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/

Comment: I had asked for the desktop install not the touch. Thank you for the effort, however do you know how to install Ubuntu for Nexus 7 (desktop) that would be 13.10?

Comment: Check out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/323259/installing-ubuntu-on-nexus-7 *Basically, that repository is not currently available. This we be replaced by something, once the focus moves from 'phablet' build.*