# Ubuntu Desktop for Nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Will the Ubuntu Desktop for Nexus 7 development continue, or is the sole development focus now on Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: I have seen this answered before, but will need to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the answer seems to be no.

This seems to be answered in the first answer in this question (though the supporting link doesn't say anything about ubuntu-core, just that Canonical is focusing on a mobile OS): [Installing Ubuntu on Nexus 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323259/installing-ubuntu-on-nexus-7)