# Ubuntu Touch install syntax error

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I encountered an error while trying to install Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4.

After the following command:

```
phablet-flash (cdimage-touch|cdimage-legacy|ubuntu-system|community) -b
```

I received an error saying: `syntax error near unexpected token 'cdimage-touch'`

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The line `phablet-flash (cdimage-touch|cdimage-legacy|ubuntu-system|community) -b` actually means *chose **one** of the commands in brackets*.

---

Your correct command is likely to be:

```
phablet-flash cdimage-touch -b
```