# phablet-flash: error: too few arguments

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I try to install Ubuntu touch into my nexus 10 (ver: 4.3)Now I start to work on the 4th step - Downloading & Deploying Image to Device

**I wrote:** `phablet-flash (cdimage-touch|cdimage-legacy|ubuntu-system|community) -b`

**then:** `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'cdimage-touch'`

**I wrote:** `phablet-flash -b`

**then:** `usage: phablet-flash [-h]
phablet-flash: error:too few arguments`

So what I should do next?

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/336635/169736

Answer (score -1):

Try: 
    phablet-flash  cdimage-touch -b

to flash the latest stable image.